# How to best structure this data in MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql

I am building a scheduling application for a production facility.

There are 8 separate production cells in the building and, for each given day, each cell has a different production capacity (ex. production cell A has 6 people working on 06-01-2020).

I am trying to figure out the best way to structure this data so it can be easily updated via a nightly sync with their ERP.

Presently, I am storing all of the data in one table as follows:

```
ID (primary key) | Date | Production Cell ID | Resource
```

Neither the Date, Production Cell ID, nor Resource can be Unique, as each of them will have duplicates many, many times over.

Given this, I am unclear on how to run a query to 1) check if a row exists and 2) insert or update accordingly.

Is there a better way to structure this data?

For instance, should each Production Cell be its own table with its own list of Dates?

Comment: Surely (Date, Production Cell ID, Resource) *can* be unique !?!

Comment: How so? I understand that Unique means no duplicate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **compound unique index** would serve your purposes quite well. It allows you to specify a set of columns, such that the combination of data in those columns must be unique.

For your purposes:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX pcell_date_index
ON production_cell_data(date,cell_id);
```

This assumes that you should only have one row for any combination of production cell + date.

Queries to get/update a unique row (without the ID) will need to include both columns in the where clause, but should perform very well with the index.

Comment: Obviously the table/column names in my query are guesses, as you didn't provide the specific details of your current table.

Comment: Thank you, I'll read up on compound unique indexes. I am new to MySQL and not familiar with many of the tools available.

Comment: Good plan. Also, after you've finished studying, please come back and provide some feedback on my answer. Vote up/accept if it is "right" or helpful, or comment/vote down if I said something wrong. You can also provide your own answer if you just find a different solution independently. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Your solution worked. I created a unique key using the following statement: `ALTER TABLE `resource` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`date`, `idTable`);` and then updated my INSERT statement with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Because I am knew to stack overflow, I am unable to upvote or mark your answer as correct, unfortunately.